# why AsynchronousFileChannel for multi-thread I/Os throws java.nio.file.FileSystemException?

Tags: java, multithreading, io, text-files, nio

I want to have a class which instances from different threads will write or read from the same file. Below is pretty much the write operation but I get a `java.nio.file.FileSystemException`. I am using 2 instances as a trivial multi-thread access but I can't make it work

```
try {
     fileChannel = AsynchronousFileChannel.open(Paths.get("Filename.txt"), 
         StandardOpenOption.READ,
         StandardOpenOption.WRITE);
} catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
Future<Integer> writeFuture = 
    fileChannel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(obj.toString().getBytes()), position);    
try {
    fileChannel.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

EDIT:

The stacktrace:

java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\workspace\TileMap\FileMap.txt: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

```
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:86)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:90)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsChannelFactory.newAsynchronousFileChannel(WindowsChannelFactory.java:199)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newAsynchronousFileChannel(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:138)
at java.nio.channels.AsynchronousFileChannel.open(AsynchronousFileChannel.java:248)
at java.nio.channels.AsynchronousFileChannel.open(AsynchronousFileChannel.java:300)
at slick.FileMap.updateFiguredMap(FileMap.java:84)
at agents.PlayerMap.seeFiguredMap(PlayerMap.java:196)
at agents.TickerExplorerRandomMapFile.seeFiguredMap(TickerExplorerRandomMapFile.java:206)
at agents.TickerExplorerRandomMapFile$1.onTick(TickerExplorerRandomMapFile.java:236)
at jade.core.behaviours.TickerBehaviour.action(TickerBehaviour.java:72)
at jade.core.behaviours.Behaviour.actionWrapper(Behaviour.java:344)
at jade.core.Agent$ActiveLifeCycle.execute(Agent.java:1532)
at jade.core.Agent.run(Agent.java:1471)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: Can you share the complete stack trace?

Comment: I added the stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

When your thread are finished updating the file, then it should close the stream. If a thread has an active file handle or it has not release the handle after finishing the update, then other thread will not be able to get the file handle. Most probably, that is the reason why you are getting the exception saying

> "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by
>   another process."

Comment: Isn't what fileChannel.close() does? It closes the stream

Comment: Yes thats correct fileChannel.close ultimately calls the fileInputStream.close. Is the access to the method is synchronized ? To be sure only one thread is working on the file at a time?

Comment: I don't know how to sync it.Can you suggest something?